# Packaging succeeded, but publishing failed to ArcGIS for Server?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, arcgis-server

I am using ArcGIS Server 10.1. I have tried all the suggested solutions above this thread but still unable/failed to create/execute service. The error message I get is:

> Packaging succeeded, but publishing failed. ERROR 001369: Failed to
>   create the service Please consult the GP Results Window for enhanced
>   error description

Comment: Check this Esri article: [Error:  Packaging succeeded, but publishing failed. ERROR 001369: Failed to create the service](http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/40391)

Comment: What does the GP Results window say? Do you have admin or publishing rights on the GIS server?

Comment: Thanks Mintx. Apparently, the error was between the ArcGIS Server and MS SQL Server. It was a path and configuration issue especially with the sde geodatabase. I had to keep all my data in the sde geodatabase and it worked fine. Thanks again.

Comment: Have you guys find a solution why does this massage appears, I am using ArcGIS 10.2.2, and trying to publish an mxd that contains feature classes for gdb file .

Comment: Can you please answer your own question and mark it as answered?

Comment: In my case, there was an inconsistent state. The service folder was not present in directories\arcgissystem\arcgisinput\, but it was listed in the ArcGIS manager. Removing the service in the manager manually and/ or restarting the PublishingService resolved the issue.